# Circular div, vertical and horizontal center alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#playhead-outercircle{
width:10px;
height:10px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-radius:100px;
cursor:pointer;
}
#playhead-innercircle{
width:7px;
height:7px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-radius:100px;
cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="playhead">
<div id="playhead-outercircle"><div id="playhead-innercircle"></div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's how it looks like:

[image: output]

how, do i make the inner div, appear right in the middle of the parent, both vertically and horizontally?

Please help...

Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to keep the same dimensions, simply add padding to `#playhead-outercircle`

```
#playhead-outercircle {
   width:10px;
   height:10px;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:1px;
   border-radius:100px;
   cursor:pointer;
   padding: 1px 0 0 1px;
}
```

**Demo** - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ut8u/)

Comment: No offence to the answer but this is technically an incorrect approach to the solution

Answer (score 2):

The dimensions you are using is very small, so I've increased it proportionately for demonstration purposes

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KKF6C/)

```
#playhead-outercircle{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-radius:100px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: relative;
}

#playhead-innercircle{
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-radius:100px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -35px;
    margin-top: -35px;
}
```

Explanation:

We are using `position: relative;` for the container `div`  so that the `absolute div` doesn't roll out in the wild, than we use `left, top` `50%` and than negate the 1/2 of the `height` and `width` from the inner `div` to position it in the exact center of the container element.

> Note: You are using very small `px` size so I would suggest you to
>   round that up at 8 or 6 so you can negate the dimensions easily. Also you are using a 
>   `1px` border, that should be considered as well

Comment: no, but i am designing playheads, for my video player, is it impossible for small play heads

Comment: @tenstar than you should check out [font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) :)